# Markdown: How to resize image defined with a base64 data uri

Tags: base64, markdown, data-uri, base64url

In markdown, I would like to embed a base64 image data uri.

`![description](data:image/png;base64, --base64 png--)`

Is there any way to resize the rendered image in markdown?

Answer (score 1):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40342873/2983771), it is allowed and encouraged to use HTML within markdown. So you can embed and resize a base64 image using the `img` [tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) in HTML by adding the data uri in the `src` attribute as follows.

```html
<img width="20" height="15" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>
```

Comment: I am aware of this method. Wanted a markdown only solution.

Comment: @gaitat John Gruber, the co-creator of markdown, mentioned in his website that "As of this writing, Markdown has no syntax for specifying the dimensions of an image; if this is important to you, you can simply use regular HTML <img> tags." https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img